# C# - Custom HTML Helper

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, html-helper

I have the following code to set up a variable in my view model.

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

I also have a Bootstrap Helper class which creates text boxes using the following code:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextboxGroupFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    BootstrapInputSizes? width = BootstrapInputSizes.Defalut)
{
    var placeholder = string.Empty;

    if (html.ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("placeholder"))
    {
        placeholder = html.ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["placeholder"] as string;
    }

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"form-group col-xs-12\">");
    sb.AppendLine(html.LabelFor(expression, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" }).ToHtmlString());
    sb.AppendLine("<div class=\" col-sm-6\">");
    sb.AppendLine(html.TextBoxFor(expression,
        new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = placeholder }).ToHtmlString());
    sb.AppendLine("</div></div>");
    return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```

How would I be able to make the following line:

```
sb.AppendLine(html.TextBoxFor(expression,
                new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = placeholder }).ToHtmlString());
```

Look like:

```
sb.AppendLine(html.TextBoxFor(expression,
               new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = placeholder , @type ="Password"}).ToHtmlString());
```

Depending on whether or not the DataType is set to "Password"?

Thanks guys/girls!

Answer (score 2):

You could get the `ModelMetadata` of the property to which the lambda expression is pointing using the [`FromLambdaExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428393%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method and then it is a simple matter of inspecting the value of the [`DataTypeName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata.datatypename%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) property:

```
var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
if (metadata.DataTypeName == "Password")
{
    ... your model property was decorated with [DataType(DataType.Password)]
}
```

Comment: Great answer, Regarding actually setting the type.. Is there a one liner way to do it e.g. If Password Type = Password, If Email Type=Email if nothing type = null

Comment: There is a one-liner but I think that it would be ugly in this situation. Your code would be more readable with an if/else statement to generate a `TextBoxFor` or a `Passwordfor` helper. As far as your previous comment about *But @Type = Null doesnt work in C#*, I don't quite understand what this sentence means as a matter of fact.